# importの方法

Tags: python, python3

class_a.pyに基底クラスclass_common()を作り、派生クラスclass_aを同じclass_a.pyに記述、もう一方の派生クラスclass_bをclass.pyに記述しています。
それぞれ機能単位で派生クラスのファイルを分けています。
機能ごとにテストするため、個別ファイルで実行したいと考えています。

class_a.pyの実行時には問題がありません。
class_b.pyの実行時にはAttributeErrorとなり、class_bの基底クラスclass_aにclass_commonがないというエラーになります。

この場合、どう記述すればよいのでしょうか？
ご教示をお願いします。

以下にコードを示します。

```
# class_a.py
import class_b

class class_common():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cc = 100
        return

class class_a(class_common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.A = 10

    def a(self,b):
        B = class_b.class_b()
        a = 1
        return self.cc-B.B+b+a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = class_a()
    print(c.a(30))
```

```
#class_b.py
import class_a

class class_b(class_a.class_common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.B=20
        return

    def b(self,a):
        A = class_a.class_a()
        b = -1
        return self.cc-b-a+A.A


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = class_b()
    print(c.b(30))
```

Comment: `class_common`をまた別の独立ファイルにして、`class_a`,`class_b`の双方で`import`するとかでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。シンプルにやはりその方法が良いようですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基底クラスを個別ファイルにすることで解決しました。

```
# class_common.py
class class_common():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cc = 100
        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = class_a()
    print(c.a(30))
```

```
# class_a.py
import class_common as COM
import class_b

class class_a(COM.class_common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.A = 10

    def a(self,b):
        B = class_b.class_b()
        a = 1
        return self.cc-B.B+b+a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = class_a()
    print(c.a(30))
```

```
#class_b.py
import class_common as COM
import class_a

class class_b(COM.class_common):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.B=20
        return

    def b(self,a):
        A = class_a.class_a()
        b = -1
        return self.cc-b-a+A.A


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = class_b()
    print(c.b(30))
```